# Change multiple table names in SQL Server using sp_rename dynamically

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dynamic-sql, sp-rename

I'm trying to change a series of table names in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard edition using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018.

The code I've been transmitting is based on the following code:

```
use DatabaseX

declare @RunRW varchar(MAX)
declare @ArVC varchar(4)
declare @StartAr smallint
declare @SlutAr smallint
declare @Ar smallint

set @StartAr = 2000
set @SlutAr = 2018
set @Ar = @StartAr

while @Ar <= @SlutAr
begin
    set @ArVC = cast(@Ar as varchar)

    set @RunRW = '
        exec sp_rename ''TMP_Table_Name_' + @ArVC + ',''Table_Name_' + @ArVC + ''

    exec (@RunRW)

    set @Ar = @Ar + 1
end
```

I've tried different numbers of quotion marks in my `exec sp_rename` syntax. It seems that I can move around the failure by changing these. The example code above delivers the error message below:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TMP_Table_Name_2000'.

I've also tried with four quotes instead of two.

Another try was to run the stored procedure dynamically like it is, without the `@RunRW` variable. That didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong/missing or is it not possible to run `sp_rename` with dynamic code?

Comment: Why do you *want* to do this? This seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: If you do need to inject (object) names **safely** into a dynamic statement as well, you need to be using `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Also, whever you are declaring a datatype, **always** declare your length, scale or precision. You have `cast(@Ar as varchar)` in there, and not declaring the data type properly can result in unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do this, personally, I would do it this way. Using the `sys` objects you can effect only the objects that exist (which means if 2018 doesn't exist no error), and you properly quote the values. As you're only removing `'TMP_'` from the start as well, you can use `STUFF` to replace those characters with `''`:

```
DECLARE @Start int = 2000,
        @End int = 2018;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);


SET @SQL = (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'EXEC sp_rename N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name] + N'.' + t.[name],'''') + N',N' + QUOTENAME(STUFF(t.[name],1,4,''),'''') + N';',NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10))
            FROM sys.schemas s
                 JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
            WHERE t.[name] LIKE N'TMP_Table_Name_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
              AND TRY_CONVERT(int,RIGHT(t.[name],4)) BETWEEN @Start AND @End)

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This'll likely also perform faster than a `WHILE`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It will be most helpful in the future, since I have quite a lot of tables with the prefix "tmp" which is generated when the table is created. And I would also like to thank you for the adjustments in my question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have missed the closing quote from both the table names.  If you change:

```
set @RunRW = '
        exec sp_rename ''TMP_Table_Name_' + @ArVC + ',''Table_Name_' + @ArVC + ''
```

to be

```
set @RunRW = '
    exec sp_rename ''TMP_Table_Name_' + @ArVC + ''',''Table_Name_' + @ArVC + ''''
```

it will remove the error.